# To copy values from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and paste it at desired location using vba

Tags: excel, vba

My objective is to copy values from cells in sheet 1 "B5" onwards and paste it to sheet 2 "C11" onwards below is the code not working properly

```
Sub SCMPROCUREMENT()

' SUPPLY CHAIN MANAGEMENT PROCUREMENT


Worksheets("Sheet1").Select


Range("B5:B100000").Select

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 5 To finalrow

If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Font.Bold = False Then

Worksheets("sheet1").Select

Cells(x, 2).Select

Selection.Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C11").Select


ActiveSheet.Paste


End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: `1.`Why do you say it's not workig properly? `2.`Can you point out the exact error line? `3.`Have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode using `F8`? If you can answer these 3 questions, then it helps us to help you =)

Answer (score 1):

a) your *ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C11")* doesn't work like that

b) you need a counter for the second list, otherwise you keep overwriting C11

```
Sub SCMPROCUREMENT()

    ' SUPPLY CHAIN MANAGEMENT PROCUREMENT

    Dim count As Integer

    For x = 5 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Font.Bold = False Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Copy

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(11 + count, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            count = count + 1

        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, after running macro suggested by you there flashes a msg.  "SELECT METHOD OF RANGE CLASS FAILED" for line Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(11 + count, 3).Select . can it be fixed? Thanks Amit Ojha

Comment: Sir, after running macro suggested by you there flashes a msg.  "SELECT METHOD OF RANGE CLASS FAILED" for line Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(11 + count, 3).Select . and it can be fixed by using - Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
            
            Cells(11 + count, 3).Select-  Thanks Amit Ojha

Comment: Glad it worked for you. By marking an answer as appropriate, you show that the issue has been solved, so that no one else thinks he has to come here to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SCMPROCUREMENT()

    ' SUPPLY CHAIN MANAGEMENT PROCUREMENT

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim count As Integer

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For x = 5 To .Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            If .Cells(x, 2).Font.Bold = False Then

                .Cells(x, 2).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(11 + count, 3)
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next x

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```